# Porting create_api.sh to python script

Tags: python-3.x, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

Is there any way to call cloud formation "aws cloudformation deploy --template-file ./cloudformation-api.yml --stack-name "$STACK_PREFIX-api-$ENV_NAME" --no-fail-on-empty-changeset --parameter-overrides pEnv=$ENV_NAME apiGatewayStageName=$ENV_NAME pApplicationName=dmdm"

from a python script I was checking python boto3 or awscli python api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use [Boto3 create_stack API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.create_stack)

Here is the example: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/deploy-cloudformation-stacks-at-the-click-of-a-button/